# 'from receipt' of a firm order

Tags: prepositions, definite-article

> The goods will be shipped 3 days **from receipt** of a firm order.

1) Will replacing 'from' with 'after' still convey the same meaning?

2) I suspect there is a definite article missing in front of 'receipt'; is using 'the' required, optional or unnecessary?

Comment: Yes, and optional.  1) In this context, there is little difference in meaning between "from", "after" and "following", but "from" is the more natural choice.  2) The noun "receipt" (when it means the act or time of receiving, as it does here, rather than meaning the physical record of a transaction) can be used as either a countable or uncountable noun.  Here, I find the uncountable sense to be slightly more natural because it represents a hypothetical future action.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan Thank you for your explanation. It seems you're implying that using the definite article would be more natural for a (hypothetical) complete action. For instance, let's consider the following sentence: "The return shipment must take place within 14 days from the receipt of the order." Here, receipt is used with 'the' since it is assumes that the receipt of the order has already taken place before returning the shipment. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan, why don't you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gary Botnovcan has answered this  in the comments.

> Yes, and optional.
>
> 1) In this context, there is little difference in meaning between "from", "after" and "following", but "from" is the more natural choice.
>
> 2) The noun "receipt" (when it means the act or time of receiving, as it does here, rather than meaning the physical record of a transaction) can be used as either a countable or uncountable noun. Here, I find the uncountable sense to be slightly more natural because it represents a hypothetical future action.